# How to use MySQL IN with Joomla query - Syntax Issue

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a variable called `$del_ids` which is using the `array_keys()` function:

```
$del_ids = implode("','", array_keys($_POST['gallery']));
```

`$del_ids` outputs an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [2] => on
    [4] => on
)
```

And I need to delete any rows which have an id which matches IN the array.  If I use procedural PHP it works great:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM studio_sessions WHERE id IN('$del_ids')";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

When I convert this to Joomla query, I can't get the IN syntax correctly.  For example:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$conditions = array(
    $db->quoteName('id' . ' IN ' . $del_ids) 
);

$query->delete($db->quoteName('#__studio_sessions'));
$query->where($conditions);

$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->execute();
```

I get this error:

```
1054 Unknown column 'id IN 2','4' in 'where clause' SQL=DELETE FROM `vsem6_studio_sessions` WHERE `id IN 2','4`
```

Looks like I'm missing some single quotes maybe around the id and 2, but I can't get the syntax right - can anyone spot the issue?

Comment: after implode function variable $del_ids must be string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$db->quoteName('id' . ' IN ' . $del_ids)`

Is incorrect.  You are treating that whole long strng as a name which is why it thinks that 'id IN('2','4')' is the column name.

Try
`$db->quoteName('id') . ' IN (' . $del_ids .')'`

Also your initial implode should be

```
$del_ids = implode(',', array_keys($_POST['gallery']));
```

Otherwise you will get `','` as the separator rather than `'`.

Comment: thanks, I get:  1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '','4)' at line 3 SQL=DELETE FROM `vsem6_studio_sessions` WHERE `id` IN (2','4)

Comment: It's strange that you are getting quote marks round the comma there ...  can you please do `var_dump($del_ids)`?

Comment: `$del_ids = implode(',', array_keys($_POST['gallery']));`

Comment: fixing the implode as requested worked with the suggest query!